# Laravel route works with internal webserver but not with WAMP

Tags: laravel

I defined the following route in /app/Http/routes.php:

```
Route::get('products', function () {
    return App\Product::all();
});
```

My Laravel Installation sits in C:\wamp\www\product-service\

When running WAMP, Laravels Welcome Page will be displayed (URL: http://localhost/product-service/public/)
However, the URL http://localhost/product-service/public/products won't work, Error Message "Not Found. The requested URL /product-service/public/product was not found on this server".

Now, when I start the internal test server

> php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1

The URL http://localhost:8000/products will work fine.

Why is that?

Comment: please check is that mod_rewrite enable in your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if you've the proper .htaccess in your public folder. If the file is present, maybe your WAMP environment has the mod_rewrite module disabled. Check the apache conf file in:

```
{wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

check for this line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

remove the # at the beginning. Check then for the AllowedOverride param and change No to All. Restart your apache server and give it a try. Last but no least, check the Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls) for another htaccess file that can be useful to you